# Как проскролить к какому-то элементу?

Tags: activity, android

Есть элемент, который не вмещается в рамки экрана. Мне нужно проскролить скролл так, чтобы элемент попал в рамки видимости

[image]

p.s. Вложных layout и других премудростей нет

p.p.s Если по схемке, то нужно проскроллить к какому-нибудь iogh например

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: @Gorets разве непонятно, что речь идёт **не от имени пользователя, а от разработчика**?!

Comment: понятно, но от разработчика код хочется видеть, по вопросу непонятно, что ты использовал, какая вложенность леяутов, где скролл

Comment: Я так понял, суть вопроса в том, как задать начальное положение какого-тонибудь ScrollView?

Comment: @Евгений Василенко, не совсем. Надо установить такое положение, чтобы был виден какой-нибудь элемент, например iogh

Comment: @woesss спасибо, это то, что надо. Переделайте в ответ - примем и плюсанём

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может это вам подойдёт:

```
   scrollView.scrollTo(0, yourView.getTop());
```

Если элементов мало то можно в конец:

```
   scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```